# URL hide #anchor-text from string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few URLs which include anchor text on the end. I'm looking to mask or hide the #anchor-text from the end of my URL.

I have tried the following but have not had any luck.

```
<div>
<a href="/about-us/how-to-book" onclick="document.location.href = '/about-us/how-to-book#page-anchor'; return false;" title="How To Book">How to book</a>
</div>
```

I've checked out the other posts in regards to this issue but they seem to be pretty dated and the solutions did not fit.

Any assistance or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what is not working with that code above?

Comment: It doesn't scroll down to the anchor point

Comment: Does the url have the anchor on it when the page loads?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to remove accessibility... but you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API with an onload event to remove it. This would have to be embedded in your how-to-book page.

Comment: @epascarello it does

Comment: @epascarello currently the code above scrolls me down to the relevant section but doesn't mask the #page-anchor from the URL

Comment: You can not mask it if you actually want it to scroll on another page! What is the big deal with it being in the URL? That is how URLS work.

Comment: @epascarello it looks ugly haha, would you really want that #page-anchor displaying on all of your urls?

Comment: Well guess what? If you use anchors and you need it to scroll to that section, you need to live with the ugliness. That is how targeted URLS work. If you are not navigating away, you can manually scroll to the anchor with code, but if you are on another page, you can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing my tatic.

Instead of using anchor tags, I used a scrollTop feature to say on page load scroll past the hero image.